# Slow vim startup time -- seemingly unrelated to plugins

Tags: vim

When I open vim (or gvim) on MacOS X, the window opens immediately, but there is a pause of about a second before the cursor appears.  I've profiled my plugins, but their startup times don't account for the length of the pause:

```
ExecTime"   "PluginName"
42.126  "syntastic"
15.896  "unite.vim"
7.116   "vim-textobj-rubyblock"
6.77    "vim-fugitive"
6.653   "vim-easymotion"
4.707   "tabular"
1.787   "neomru.vim"
1.585   "vim-table-mode"
1.376   "tagbar"
1.106   "L9"
1.053   "vim-textobj-user"
1.042   "neoyank.vim"
1.027   "vim-surround"
0.679   "vim-exchange"
0.667   "Vundle.vim"
0.645   "neocomplete.vim"
0.512   "neosnippet.vim"
0.355   "vim-commentary"
0.321   "restore_view.vim"
0.187   "ag.vim"
0.167   "vimproc.vim"
0.15    "tern_for_vim"
0.115   "vim-javascript-syntax"
0.114   "scss-syntax.vim"
0.113   "vim-slim"
0.099   "vim-snippets"
0.077   "Rename"
```

If I use the `--startuptime` flag it produces a file 2 million lines long, and I don't know how to extract the relevant info.

What could be causing the problem?  How else can I debug it?